# XAF Criteria Operator Returns Nothing

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I have tried to filter some records without success using `CriteriaOperator.Parse`. Im sure there are records that equal my criteria.

Can you show me how can i do it?

**Current Code**

uow = `UnitOfWork` and im sure its not null

```
XPCollection coll = new XPCollection(uow, typeof(HataBildirim), CriteriaOperator.Parse(" [HataTespitYeri] = ? and [Tarih] > ? and ([CreatedOn] > ? OR [LastModifiedOn] > ?)",hatatespityeri, convservertarih, senkdate));
```

Comment: There are 4 parameters (question marks) in criteria, but you pass only 3: "hatatespityeri, convservertarih, senkdate". Is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

As TSV comments, the problem is almost certainly due to you only passing three parameter values where there are four placeholders in your criteria.

Assuming that your "senkdate" is supposed to be compared to both [CreatedOn] and [LastModifiedOn] just pass it twice:

```
XPCollection coll = new XPCollection(uow, typeof(HataBildirim), CriteriaOperator.Parse("[HataTespitYeri] = ? and [Tarih] > ? and ([CreatedOn] > ? OR [LastModifiedOn] > ?)",hatatespityeri, convservertarih, senkdate, senkdate));
```